# Multi-class optimal threshold selection

Tags: classification, confusion-matrix, threshold

What are the methods typically used for optimal threshold selection of multiclass classification problem ?
I implemented the detector/classifier and generated the confusion matrix, but would like to methodically select the correct threshold. If possible, a reference to materials as opposed to scikit-learn or API links, since I would be implementing the method.

Comment: What are the costs associated with the various forms of misclassification e.g., calling an A a B or calling a C an A or calling an A a C? // Why do you have to use thresholds at all? Why not work with the probabilities?

Comment: Can you give an example ? Probabilities will differ when using the detector with real-time data compared to training/testing data. But still, how would an estimation of the probabilities be related to threshold?

Comment: The threshold is necessary because this is Likelihood ratio test based detector. The threshold is selected according to a balance between the TPR and FPR as in the ROC

Comment: If you are not dealing with probabilities, then what kind of threshold do you seek?

Comment: If you are referring to probabilities represented by the confusion matrix normalized to 1 for each row, then yes I have that. What I am asking is, the optimal heuristic threshold, in the case of binary classification it is elbow point on the ROC, but in multi-class classification, each class has its own ROC, how to select a threshold such that detector/classifier performance is maximized across all the classes

Comment: Note, that that this is a log likelihood ratio test based detector/classifier, rather than a bayesian based approach

Comment: Your model most likely predicts probabilities of class membership, not hard classifications. What kind of model are you using? Are you familiar with Frank Harrell's discussion about the differences between classification and tendency estimation? [1](https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/) [2](https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/) // Nothing about my question gets into a LRT vs Bayesian discussion.

Comment: There is no model, I am in fact dealing with decision (classification as opposed to regressive model, although there is AR parameter estimation as intermediary step), but the test is  log-likelihood ratio computation based on the information provided in the spectral content. A ratio test of a reference vector compared to another, if it is larger than a threshold, a significant variance exists and hence likely an anomaly.  Your reference is a good read. Thank u. I'm not sure if it applies in this case

Comment: If the decisions are already made, then it does not sound like you have any kind of decision threshold to set. Perhaps you can edit your original question to explain in more detail what you want to do.